# Assign an array of arrays

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have the following array:

```
GLfloat vertex[(vertexnm+2)][3];
```

A simple assignment to an element of the outer array is not possible:

```
vertex[0] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

Which results in `Array type 'GLfloat [3]' is not assignable`.

The following way seems to be possible:

```
*(vertex[0]) = *new GLfloat[3] {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

But it does not seem like it's a good solution. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: You might use `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately arrays are only little more than glorifed pointers in C which
e.g. means here that they don't copy like you expect (e.g. like objects).

C++11 introduces a new abstraction for arrays which make arrays behave much
more like you expect, e.g. they can be copied or assigned. With pre-C++11 compilers/standard libraries you can use the `array` class from TR1 in `tr1/array`.

```
#include <array>

int main() {
  typedef std::array<GLfloat, 3> vertex;
  std::array<vertex, vertexnm + 2> a;
  a[0] = vertex{0, 0, 0};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though C-style arrays are certainly not just "glorified pointers", naked C-style arrays are not assignable, regardless of how you slice it. C++11 does not change anything in that regard.

Your

```
*(vertex[0]) = *new GLfloat[3] {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

does not do what you think it does. On the left-hand side `vertex[0]` decays to the pointer to `vertex[0][0]`, which you dereference with the `*`. So, the left-hand size is simply `vertex[0][0]`.

Meanwhile, `new GLfloat[3] {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}` returns a pointer to the `[0]` element of the newly allocated nameless array. The `*` dereferences that pointer, giving you access to that `[0]` element.

The above means that your assignment is really equivalent to

```
vertex[0][0] = nameless_dynamic_array[0];
```

i.e. it does

```
vertex[0][0] = 0.0f;
```

with the new-ed array becoming a memory leak.

In order to assign an array as a whole, you have to wrap it into a class (`std::array` being a standard wrapper). Or, if you for some reason have to use naked C-style arrays, use `std::copy` or even `memcpy` for copying data from one array to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative:

```
 static const int myFirstArray[] = {16,2,77};
 static const int mySecondArray[] = {84,64,1};

 std::vector< std::vector<int> > myArray(3);
 myArray[0] = std::vector<int>(myFirstArray, myFirstArray + sizeof(myFirstArray) / sizeof(myFirstArray[0]) );
 myArray[1] = std::vector<int>(mySecondArray, mySecondArray + sizeof(mySecondArray) / sizeof(mySecondArray[0]) );
 //prints:
 //16 2 77
 //84 64 1
 for (unsigned int i=0;i<myArray.size();++i){
    for (unsigned int j=0;j<myArray[i].size();++j){
        std::cout << myArray[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```